# maching source MAC address in nftables

Tags: linux, mac-address, nftables

I want to match all data from `ens19` with the mac address `88:7e:25:d3:90:0b` use table 147.

My idea is to mark the data from `88:7e:25:d3:90:0b` and give it a fwmark 14. Then use ip rule to the specified route table

So I make this command

```
nft add rule filter input iif ens19 ether saddr = 88:7e:25:d3:90:0b mark set 147
Error: syntax error, unexpected '='
add rule filter input iif ens19 ether saddr = 88:7e:25:d3:90:0b mark set 147
```

What is the correct way to do this command?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Matching_packet_headers), the syntax you want is:

```
nft add rule filter input iif ens19 ether saddr 88:7e:25:d3:90:0b mark set 147
```

Comment: `root@:~# nft add rule filter input iif ens19 ether saddr 88:7e:25:d3:90:0b mark set 147
Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory
add rule filter input iif ens19 ether saddr 88:7e:25:d3:90:0b mark set 147
         ^^^^^^
`

Comment: Thanks for helping, but this syntax is not correct

Comment: `nft add table ip filter
nft add chain ip filter input { type filter hook input priority 0 \; } # create chain
nft add rule filter input iif ens19 ether saddr 88:7e:25:d3:90:0b mark set 147
`

Comment: After I add  ip filter chain input it works